# How to solve the error "Load address not aligned to word boundary" in RISC-V?

Tags: mips, riscv, mars-simulator, rars-simulator

I'm working on translating MIPS assembly programs written for the MARS simulator into RISCV assembly for RARS simulator.

This program is to divide the source image from a BMP file into 3 by 4 pieces and put them in new order after inputting it from console.

But after converting, when I ran the code, an error occurred.

Checking it step by step, I found this error occurred in the following line.

```
lw t0, 0(t2)                # load word value from input file
```

in

```
copyLoop2:

    blt s1, s3, copyLoop2after 
    lw t0, 0(t2)                # load word value from input file
    sw t0, 0(t3)            # save word value to output file
    addi t2, t2, 4      # jump t2 into next word
    addi t3, t3, 4      # jump t3 into next word
    addi s3, s3, 1
    j copyLoop2
```

The error message is

```
Load address not aligned to word boundary 0x100100e2
```

But in MIPS, it worked correctly. Also, when I replaced `lw` with `lb` and `sw` with `sb`, an error didn't occur, but it didn't work properly. It didn't output any files.

Then, the following is the whole program of MIPS.

```
# Patch 1.1
# Changelog:
# - readBmp and writeBmp now slightly more universal
# - optimized multiplication by a power of 2 (now using sll)

.eqv    bmpFileSize 230454
.eqv    bytesPerRow 960
.eqv    bytesPerColumnSegment 240
.eqv    bytesPerRowSegment 76800
.eqv    bytesJumpNextRow 720

.data   
        
    array:      .space  96  # reserve space for array of numbers by which to order the segments in dest.bmp
    checkArray: .word   1,1,1,2,1,3,1,4,2,1,2,2,2,3,2,4,3,1,3,2,3,3,3,4 # reserve space for array used in checking the input string
    userInput:  .space  25  # reserve space for initial user input
    .align  4
    res1:   .space  2
    inputImage: .space  bmpFileSize # reserve space for input file data
    .align  4
    res2:   .space  2
    outputImage:    .space  bmpFileSize     # reserve space for output file data
    inputImageName: .asciiz "source.bmp"
    outputImageName:.asciiz "dest.bmp"
    inputMessage:   .asciiz "Please input the desired order in the format 'number1number2number3...'. NO SPACES!!!\nFor instance 111213142122232431323334.\nAll numbers need to be used\n"
    inputTab:   .asciiz "\n"
    inputFileErrorMessage:  .asciiz "Encountered a problem while trying to open the input file. Exiting the program"
    outputFileErrorMessage: .asciiz "Encountered a problem while trying to open the output file. Exiting the program"
    checkErrorMessage:  .asciiz "checkString error: Incorrect input string"
    
.text

######## Initial file handling ###############
    
    # handle source.bmp and dest.bmp reading into memory
    la $a0, inputImageName
    la $a1, outputImageName
    move $t8, $a1
    jal readBmp

######## User input section ##################

    # print 'give input' message
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, inputMessage
    syscall
    
    # get user input
    li $v0, 8
    la $a0, userInput
    li $a1, 25
    syscall
    
    # print newline
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, inputTab
    syscall
    
    # loop over string and put data into array
    li $s4, 24
    li $s5, 0
    addi $t0, $zero, 0      # array index
    addi $t1, $zero, 0      # string index
    
arrayLoop:
    
    lb $t2, userInput($t1)      # load character bit
    subi $t2, $t2, 48       # subtract 0
    sb $t2, array($t0)      # put into array
    addi $t0, $t0, 4        # move array index
    addi $t1, $t1, 1        # move string index
    addi $s5, $s5, 1        
    blt $s5, $s4, arrayLoop
    
    # check for errors in the array
    jal checkString
    
######## Copying the segment data from inputImage into outputImage with accordance to the user input ########
    
    # set up a nested loop (upper loop 3 (row), lower 4 (column))
    li $s4, 2
    li $s5, 4
    li $s6, 0           # set first loop changing variable to 0
    li $s7, 1           # set second loop changing variable to 1
    
segmentLoop1:

    blt $s4, $s6, segmentLoopFin
    addi $s6, $s6, 1
    li $s7, 1
    j segmentLoop2

segmentLoop2:

    blt $s5, $s7, segmentLoop1
    
    # load to $a0 and $a1 from array. row first, column second
    addi $t0, $zero, 0  
    subi $t1, $s6, 1
    sll $t1, $t1, 5         # calculate offset due to row number        
    add $t0, $t0, $t1       # offset $t0
    subi $t1, $s7, 1
    sll $t1, $t1, 3         # calculate offset due to column number
    add $t0, $t0, $t1       # offset $t0
    
    lw $t2, array($t0)      # get row number
    move $a0, $t2
    addi $t0, $t0, 4
    lw $t2, array($t0)      # now column number
    move $a1, $t2
    
    # load to $a2 and $a3 from loop
    move $a2, $s6
    move $a3, $s7

    jal copySegment
    addi $s7, $s7, 1
    j segmentLoop2

segmentLoopFin:

######## Output file handling ##############
        
    # handle dest.bmp
    move $a0, $t8
    jal writeBmp

exit:

    # exit
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
    
readBmp:

    # $a0 - name of source file
    # $a1 - name of destination file
    move $t1, $a1       # save destintation file name for second half of function

    sub $sp, $sp, 4
    sw $s1, 0($sp)
    
    # input file
    # open file
    li $v0, 13
    # file name already in $a0
    li $a1, 0       # flags: read file
    li $a2, 0       # mode: ignored
    syscall
    
    # save file descriptor
    move $s1, $v0   
    
    # check if the file was opened correctly
    bltz $v0, inputFileError
    
    # read file
    li $v0, 14
    move $a0, $s1
    la $a1, inputImage
    li $a2, bmpFileSize
    syscall
    
    # close file
    li $v0, 16
    move $a0, $s1
    syscall
    
    # output file
    # open file
    li $v0, 13
    move $a0, $t1       # file name
    li $a1, 0       # flags: read file
    li $a2, 0       # mode: ignored
    syscall
    
    # save file descriptor
    move $s1, $v0
    
    # check if the file was opened correctly
    bltz $v0, outputFileError
    
    # read file
    li $v0, 14
    move $a0, $s1
    la $a1, outputImage
    li $a2, bmpFileSize
    syscall
    
    # close file
    li $v0, 16
    move $a0, $s1
    syscall
    
    lw $s1, 0($sp)
    add $sp, $sp, 4
    
    jr $ra
    
writeBmp:

    # $a0 - name of destination file
    sub $sp, $sp, 4     # push $s1
    sw $s1, 0($sp)
    
    # open file
    li $v0, 13
    # file name already in $a0
    li $a1, 1       # flags: write file
    li $a2, 0       # mode: ignored
    syscall
    
    # save file descriptor
    move $s1, $v0
    
    # check if the file was opened correctly
    bltz $v0, outputFileError
    
    # save file
    li $v0, 15
    move $a0, $s1
    la $a1, outputImage
    li $a2, bmpFileSize
    syscall
    
    # close file
    li $v0, 16
    move $a0, $s1
    syscall
    
    lw $s1, 0($sp)
    add $sp, $sp, 4
    
    jr $ra

inputFileError:

    # print error message
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, inputFileErrorMessage
    syscall
    j exit

outputFileError:

    # print error message
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, outputFileErrorMessage
    syscall
    j exit

checkString:

    # This part (from here till if2True included) is a bit convoluted, but it works.
    # Firstly there is a check if any data in the array derived from user input is zero. This doesn't do much
    # by itself, but it compliments the next part.
    # Then we iterate over checkArray in search of a pair of numbers that are the same as those in the array from user input.
    # If we don't find it it means that the number pair was not a valid one (as checkArray contains all valid number pairs).
    # If we find it we change that pair in checkArray into 00 and go to the next pair from user input. That way we won't count duplicates
    # as once a number is used, it cannot be found again. That is also why at the beggining we check for the occurence of zeroes, because if we didn't
    # an input string of 110000000000000000000000 would be accepted, which is of course wrong.
            
    # set up nested loop
    li $s4, 12
    addi $s4, $s4, -1
    li $s5, 12
    addi $s5, $s5, -1
    li $s6, 0
    li $s7, 0
    
    addi $t0, $zero, 0  # input array row index
    addi $t1, $zero, 4  # input array column index
    
checkLoop1:
    
    blt $s4, $s6, checkLoopFin
    addi $s6, $s6, 1
    li $s7, 0
    
    # check if either row number or column number are equal to 0
    lw $t4, array($t0)
    beqz $t4, checkError
    lw $t4, array($t1)
    beqz $t4, checkError    
    
    addi $t2, $zero, 0  # check array row index
    addi $t3, $zero, 4  # check array column index

checkLoop2:

    blt $s5, $s7, checkError
    
    lw $t4, array($t0)  
    lw $t5, array($t1)  
    lw $t6, checkArray($t2) 
    lw $t7, checkArray($t3) 
    
    beq $t4, $t6, if1True

checkCont:
    
    addi $t2, $t2, 8
    addi $t3, $t3, 8
    addi $s7, $s7, 1
    j checkLoop2

checkLoopFin:
        
    jr $ra

if1True:

    beq $t5, $t7, if2True
    j checkCont
    
if2True:

    li $t6, 0
    li $t7, 0
    sw $t6, checkArray($t2)
    sw $t7, checkArray($t3)
    addi $t0, $t0, 8
    addi $t1, $t1, 8
    j checkLoop1
    
checkError:

    # print error message
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, checkErrorMessage
    syscall
    j exit

copySegment:

    # $a0 - row number input
    # $a1 - column number input
    # $a2 - row number output
    # $a3 - column number output

# one register - get address of segment start point in input file
    la $t1, inputImage + 10 # address of file offset to pixel array
    lw $t2, ($t1)       # file offset to pixel array in $t2
    la $t1, inputImage  # address of bitmab
    add $t2, $t1, $t2   # address of pixel array in $t2
    # pixel address calculation
    # calculate 3 - $a0
    li $t0, 3
    sub $t1, $t0, $a0
    # move $t2 by $t0*bytesPerRowSegment
    mul $t0, $t1, bytesPerRowSegment
    add $t2, $t2, $t0
    # calculate $a1 - 1
    li $t0, 1
    sub $t1, $a1, $t0
    # move $t2 by $t0*bytesPerColumnSegment
    mul $t0, $t1, bytesPerColumnSegment
    add $t2, $t2, $t0   
    
# second register - get address of segment start point in output file
    la $t1, outputImage + 10 # address of file offset to pixel array
    lw $t3, ($t1)       # file offset to pixel array in $t2
    la $t1, outputImage # address of bitmab
    add $t3, $t1, $t3   # address of pixel array in $t2
    # pixel address calculation
    # calculate 3 - $a2
    li $t0, 3
    sub $t1, $t0, $a2
    # move $t3 by $t0*bytesPerRowSegment
    mul $t0, $t1, bytesPerRowSegment
    add $t3, $t3, $t0
    # calculate $a3 - 1
    li $t0, 1
    sub $t1, $a3, $t0
    # move $t3 by $t0*bytesPerColumnSegment
    mul $t0, $t1, bytesPerColumnSegment
    add $t3, $t3, $t0
    
    # set up nested foor loop (upper one loops 80 times (rows per segment), lower one 60 (words per row in segment))
    li $s0, 80
    addi $s0, $s0, -1
    li $s1, 60
    addi $s1, $s1, -1
    li $s2, 0           # set first loop changing variable to 0
    li $s3, 0           # set second loop changing variable to 0
    
copyLoop1:

    blt $s0, $s2, copyLoopFin
    addi $s2, $s2, 1
    li $s3, 0
    j copyLoop2

copyLoop2:

    blt $s1, $s3, copyLoop2after
    lw $t0, 0($t2)          # load word value from input file
    sw $t0, 0($t3)          # save word value to output file
    addiu $t2, $t2, 4       # jump $t2 into next word
    addiu $t3, $t3, 4       # jump $t3 into next word
    addi $s3, $s3, 1
    j copyLoop2

copyLoop2after:

    add $t2, $t2, bytesJumpNextRow  # jump $t2 into next row
    add $t3, $t3, bytesJumpNextRow  # jump $t3 into next row
    j copyLoop1

copyLoopFin:

    jr $ra
```

And the RISC-V program I converted the MIPS program to is .

```
.eqv    bmpFileSize 230454
.eqv    bytesPerRow 960
.eqv    bytesPerColumnSegment 240
.eqv    bytesPerRowSegment 76800
.eqv    bytesJumpNextRow 720

li s10 230454
li s11 960
li a4 240
li a5 76800
li a6 720

# t7->s8
# t8->s9
# move->mv
# syscall -> ecall
# asciiz-> asciz

.data   
        
    array:      .space  96  # reserve space for array of numbers by which to order the segments in dest.bmp
    checkArray: .word   1,1,1,2,1,3,1,4,2,1,2,2,2,3,2,4,3,1,3,2,3,3,3,4 # reserve space for array used in checking the input string
    userInput:  .space  25  # reserve space for initial user input
    .align  4
    res1:   .space  2
    inputImage: .space  bmpFileSize # reserve space for input file data
    .align  4
    res2:   .space  2
    outputImage:    .space  bmpFileSize     # reserve space for output file data
    inputImageName: .asciz "/private/var/folders/bf/t4py6npj0v38grsvrgvq1dx00000gn/T/hsperfdata_sotarosuzuki/source.bmp"
    outputImageName:.asciz "/private/var/folders/bf/t4py6npj0v38grsvrgvq1dx00000gn/T/hsperfdata_sotarosuzuki/dest.bmp"
    inputMessage:   .asciz "Please input the desired order in the format 'number1number2number3...'. NO SPACES!!!\nFor instance 111213142122232431323334.\nAll numbers need to be used\n"
    inputTab:   .asciz "\n"
    inputFileErrorMessage:  .asciz "Encountered a problem while trying to open the input file. Exiting the program"
    outputFileErrorMessage: .asciz "Encountered a problem while trying to open the output file. Exiting the program"
    checkErrorMessage:  .asciz "checkString error: Incorrect input string"
    
.text

######## Initial file handling ###############
    
    # handle source.bmp and dest.bmp reading into memory
    la a0, inputImageName
    la a1, outputImageName
    mv s9, a1
    jal readBmp

######## User input section ##################

    # print 'give input' message
    li a7, 4
    la a0, inputMessage
    ecall
    
    # get user input
    li a7, 8
    la a0, userInput
    li a1, 25
    ecall
    
    # print newline
    li a7, 4
    la a0, inputTab
    ecall
    
    # loop over string and put data into array
    li s4, 24
    li s5, 0
    addi t0, zero, 0        # array index
    addi t1, zero, 0        # string index
    
arrayLoop:
    
    lb t2, %lo(userInput)(t1)           # load character bit
    addi t2, t2, -48         # subtract 0
    sb t2, array, t0    # put into array
    addi t0, t0, 4      # mv array index
    addi t1, t1, 1      # mv string index
    addi s5, s5, 1      
    blt s5, s4, arrayLoop
    
    # check for errors in the array
    jal checkString
    
######## Copying the segment data from inputImage into outputImage with accordance to the user input ########
    
    # set up a nested loop (upper loop 3 (row), lower 4 (column))
    li s4, 2
    li s5, 4
    li s6, 0            # set first loop changing variable to 0
    li s7, 1            # set second loop changing variable to 1
    
segmentLoop1:

    blt s4, s6, segmentLoopFin
    addi s6, s6, 1
    li s7, 1
    j segmentLoop2

segmentLoop2:

    blt s5, s7, segmentLoop1
    
    # load to a0 and a1 from array. row first, column second
    addi t0, zero, 0    
    addi t1, s6, -1
    slli t1, t1, 5          # calculate offset due to row number        
    add t0, t0, t1      # offset t0
    addi t1, s7, -1
    slli t1, t1, 3          # calculate offset due to column number
    add t0, t0, t1      # offset t0
    
    lw t2, %lo(array)(t0)    # get row number
    mv a0, t2
    addi t0, t0, 4
    lw t2, %lo(array)(t0)       # now column number
    mv a1, t2
    
    # load to a2 and a3 from loop
    mv a2, s6
    mv a3, s7

    jal copySegment
    addi s7, s7, 1
    j segmentLoop2

segmentLoopFin:

######## Output file handling ##############
        
    # handle dest.bmp
    mv a0, s9
    jal writeBmp

exit:

    # exit
    li a7, 10
    ecall
    
readBmp:

    # a0 - name of source file
    # a1 - name of destination file
    mv t1, a1       # save destintation file name for second half of function

    addi sp, sp, -4
    sw s1, 0(sp)
    
    # input file
    # open file
    li a7, 1024
    # file name already in a0
    li a1, 0        # flags: read file
    li a2, 0        # mode: ignored
    ecall
    
    # save file descriptor
    mv s1, a7   
    
    # check if the file was opened correctly
    bltz a7, inputFileError
    
    # read file
    li a7, 63
    mv a0, s1
    la a1, inputImage
    li a2, bmpFileSize
    ecall
    
    # close file
    li a7, 57
    mv a0, s1
    ecall
    
    # output file
    # open file
    li a7, 1024
    mv a0, t1       # file name
    li a1, 0        # flags: read file
    li a2, 0        # mode: ignored
    ecall
    
    # save file descriptor
    mv s1, a7
    
    # check if the file was opened correctly
    bltz a7, outputFileError
    
    # read file
    li a7, 63
    mv a0, s1
    la a1, outputImage
    li a2, bmpFileSize
    ecall
    
    # close file
    li a7, 57
    mv a0, s1
    ecall
    
    lw s1, 0(sp)
    addi sp, sp, 4
    
    jr ra
    
writeBmp:

    # a0 - name of destination file
    addi sp, sp, -4     # push s1
    sw s1, 0(sp)
    
    # open file
    li a7, 1024
    # file name already in a0
    li a1, 1        # flags: write file
    li a2, 0        # mode: ignored
    ecall
    
    # save file descriptor
    mv s1, a7
    
    # check if the file was opened correctly
    bltz a7, outputFileError
    
    # save file
    li a7, 64
    mv a0, s1
    la a1, outputImage
    li a2, bmpFileSize
    ecall
    
    # close file
    li a7, 57
    mv a0, s1
    ecall
    
    lw s1, 0(sp)
    addi sp, sp, 4
    
    jr ra

inputFileError:

    # print error message
    li a7, 4
    la a0, inputFileErrorMessage
    ecall
    j exit

outputFileError:

    # print error message
    li a7, 4
    la a0, outputFileErrorMessage
    ecall
    j exit

checkString:

    # This part (from here till if2True included) is a bit convoluted, but it works.
    # Firstly there is a check if any data in the array derived from user input is zero. This doesn't do much
    # by itself, but it compliments the next part.
    # Then we iterate over checkArray in search of a pair of numbers that are the same as those in the array from user input.
    # If we don't find it it means that the number pair was not a valid one (as checkArray contains all valid number pairs).
    # If we find it we change that pair in checkArray into 00 and go to the next pair from user input. That way we won't count duplicates
    # as once a number is used, it cannot be found again. That is also why at the beggining we check for the occurence of zeroes, because if we didn't
    # an input string of 110000000000000000000000 would be accepted, which is of course wrong.
            
    # set up nested loop
    li s4, 12
    addi s4, s4, -1
    li s5, 12
    addi s5, s5, -1
    li s6, 0
    li s7, 0
    
    addi t0, zero, 0    # input array row index
    addi t1, zero, 4    # input array column index
    
checkLoop1:
    
    blt s4, s6, checkLoopFin
    addi s6, s6, 1
    li s7, 0
    
    # check if either row number or column number are equal to 0
    lw t4, %lo(array)(t0) 
    beqz t4, checkError
    lw t4, %lo(array)(t1) 
    beqz t4, checkError 
    
    addi t2, zero, 0    # check array row index
    addi t3, zero, 4    # check array column index

checkLoop2:

    blt s5, s7, checkError
    
    lw t4, %lo(array)(t0)    
    lw t5, %lo(array)(t1)   
    lw t6, %lo(checkArray)(t2)   
    lw s8, %lo(checkArray)(t3)   
    
    beq t4, t6, if1True

checkCont:
    
    addi t2, t2, 8
    addi t3, t3, 8
    addi s7, s7, 1
    j checkLoop2

checkLoopFin:
        
    jr ra

if1True:

    beq t5, s8, if2True
    j checkCont
    
if2True:

    li t6, 0
    li s8, 0
    sw t6, checkArray, t2
    sw s8, checkArray, t3
    addi t0, t0, 8
    addi t1, t1, 8
    j checkLoop1
    
checkError:

    # print error message
    li a7, 4
    la a0, checkErrorMessage
    ecall
    j exit

copySegment:

    # a0 - row number input
    # a1 - column number input
    # a2 - row number output
    # a3 - column number output

# one register - get address of segment start point in input file
    la t1, inputImage  # address of file offset to pixel array
    addi t1, t1, 10
    lw t2, (t1)     # file offset to pixel array in t2
    la t1, inputImage   # address of bitmab
    add t2, t1, t2  # address of pixel array in t2
    # pixel address calculation
    # calculate 3 - a0
    li t0, 3
    sub t1, t0, a0
    # mv t2 by t0*bytesPerRowSegment
    mul t0, t1, a5
    add t2, t2, t0
    # calculate a1 - 1
    li t0, 1
    sub t1, a1, t0
    # mv t2 by t0*bytesPerColumnSegment
    mul t0, t1, a4
    add t2, t2, t0  
    
# second register - get address of segment start point in output file
    
    la t1, outputImage # address of file offset to pixel array
    addi t1, t1, 10
    lw t3, (t1)     # file offset to pixel array in t2
    la t1, outputImage  # address of bitmab
    add t3, t1, t3  # address of pixel array in t2
    # pixel address calculation
    # calculate 3 - a2
    li t0, 3
    sub t1, t0, a2
    # mv t3 by t0*bytesPerRowSegment
    mul t0, t1, a5
    add t3, t3, t0
    # calculate a3 - 1
    li t0, 1
    sub t1, a3, t0
    # mv t3 by t0*bytesPerColumnSegment
    mul t0, t1, a4
    add t3, t3, t0
    
    # set up nested foor loop (upper one loops 80 times (rows per segment), lower one 60 (words per row in segment))
    li s0, 80
    addi s0, s0, -1
    li s1, 60
    addi s1, s1, -1
    li s2, 0            # set first loop changing variable to 0
    li s3, 0            # set second loop changing variable to 0
    
copyLoop1:

    blt s0, s2, copyLoopFin
    addi s2, s2, 1
    li s3, 0
    j copyLoop2

copyLoop2:

    blt s1, s3, copyLoop2after
    lw t0, 0(t2)            # load word value from input file
    sw t0, 0(t3)            # save word value to output file
    addi t2, t2, 4      # jump t2 into next word
    addi t3, t3, 4      # jump t3 into next word
    addi s3, s3, 1
    j copyLoop2

copyLoop2after:

    add t2, t2, a6  # jump t2 into next row
    add t3, t3, a6  # jump t3 into next row
    j copyLoop1

copyLoopFin:

    jr ra
```

I couldn't find the solution to convert it correclty. So could anyone help me?

And is there any way to convert it automatically?

Answer (score 1):

In riscv you have 3 possible accesses :

- word
- half word
- byte

When you perform an access you need your address to be aligned to the type of access. So for example in the case of a lw your address need to be word-aligned.

In your case the address is 0x100100e2 which is not word-aligned.
Indeed in binary it gaves us :

0b10000000000010000000011100010

Or to be word aligned the 2 lsb need to be 0 so this is why you got an error.